# missing ActionBar in material design

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to develop an Android app with AndroidStudio and the new material design and it looks great on Android 5.0 but when I test the app on my 4.4.2 phone, the ActionBar of the app is missing.

Here is my Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

the styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
</style>
```

and the build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

Do you know where the error is?

Thank you!
Simon

Comment: Are you inheriting from `ActionBarActivity`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To use the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport, you need to have your activities inherit from `ActionBarActivity`.

Quoting [Chris Banes' blog post](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/):

> If you are not currently using AppCompat, or you are starting from scratch, then here's how to set it up:
>
> - All of your Activities must extend from ActionBarActivity. It extends from FragmentActivity from the v4 support library, so you can continue to use fragments.
> - All of your themes (that want an action bar/Toolbar) must inherit from Theme.AppCompat. There are variants available including Light and NoActionBar.
> - When inflating anything to be displayed on the action bar (such as a SpinnerAdapter for list navigation in the action bar), make sure you use the action bar’s themed context retrieved via getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext().
> - You must use the static methods in MenuItemCompat for any action-related calls on a MenuItem.

**UPDATE**: Note that Google is migrating to `AppCompatActivity`. `ActionBarActivity` works — it is just a do-nothing subclass of `AppCompatActivity` — but you are better served by directly extending `AppCompatActivity` if you are going to use the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport.

Comment: But why do I need to inherit from `ActionBarActivity`? I didn't even know this class before.

Comment: @Simon: `ActionBarActivity` has been a requirement for using `appcompat-v7` since it was introduced last August. However, this is *only* if you want to use `appcompat-v7`, either because you want to support the action bar on older devices (back to API Level 7) or you want to adopt some Material Design support that was added in the `appcompat-v7` update that came out today. You are welcome to skip the library, use a regular theme, and use the native action bar if you prefer. Then, you can inherit from any activity class that you want.

Comment: OK, I want the material design on older devices so i need `ActionBarActivity`... Thanks

Comment: @Simon, Don't forget to accept this answer if you are happy with it.